# 「の向って」The point-of-view in this sentence/ when giving directional information after 「向って」

Tags: grammar, meaning, words

Sentence taken from 君の膵臓を食べたい

> 「彼女はのそのそと緩慢な動きで大きなベッド**の向って左側**に寄って仰向けに寝た。」

This sentence made me question whether my understanding of　「向う」is correct or not. It may be important to mention that the story is told from the perspective of a first-person-narrator (and this narrator is in the same room with mentioned 「彼女」). From my understanding of this definition,

むか・う〔むかふ〕【向かう】
１ ある物・方向を正面に見るように位置する。顔やからだをその方向に向ける。「鏡に―・って化粧する」「舞台に―・って右側を上手という」(https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E5%90%91%E3%81%8B%E3%81%86/#jn-214576)

the girl moves **to the left side of the bed, seen from the perspective of the narrator** (or anybody else) **facing the bed**. I tried to make this a little bit clearer with the attached image.

In other terms, my question is, if I understood it correctly that 「**向って**」means that the directional information of “left side” is given from a viewpoint looking at “the large bed”.

[image]

Comment: Related: [Question about the point of view when using の右 / の左?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/83658/5010)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your understanding is correct. The full sentence would be something like:

> 彼女はのそのそと緩慢な動きで大きなベッドの、ベッドに向って左側に寄って仰向けに寝た。

where ベッドに向かって is like an afterthought you'd put inside parentheses. The writer specified it because "the left side of the bed" changes depending on whether you're looking at the bed or laying on it.